# Timers degrading UI performance of WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, timer, responsive-design

I have a WPF C# GUI application that has a number of menu bars, buttons and grid controls.

In the main XAML form class, I have five System.Timer.Timer objects that are being declared at a class level, then being created and instantiated in the XAML form class constructor as follows (one example)

```
var factory = new TaskFactory();

                factory.StartNew(() =>
                                    {
                                        dtEmergencyQueueRefresh = new System.Timers.Timer(EmerTimeoutSecs * 1000);
                                        dtEmergencyQueueRefresh.Elapsed += dtEmergencyQueueRefresh_Tick;
                                        dtEmergencyQueueRefresh.Enabled = true;
                                    }
                                );
```

I did this so that they would definitely be started and run on background threads as I noticed slow GUI performance, but it didn't seem to help.

When I commented out all the code to start up the timers and just left them as empty declarations, the GUI performed as expected and was fine.

When I say degraded performance, the clicks still work fine but when you drop down a menu, the "hover" feature doesn't work for about 5-10 seconds so the row you are on doesn't get highlighted, unless you wait 5-10 seconds as I said.

I also tried going into the callback methods invoked by the timers and commenting out ALL code so the timers were just executing empty methods. The performance was still bad, so just having 5 timers running and calling nothing, still degraded the performance, so it is not the background processing degrading the performance, but rather having timers running at all.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this may be happening and how I can have these timers running in the background and not affecting the GUI?

Comment: Did you also try [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer)? And when you say "XAML form" you mean "WPF Window"?

Comment: Why are you starting your timers from a Task?

Comment: I haven't tried System.Threading.Timer yet - do they interact differently? And yes WPF window. As for starting them from a task, I was just starting them as usual in the constructor and wasn't 100% sure if starting the timers from the constructor meant they'd automatically run on the GUI thread so I made them start via Task just to 100% confirm they were background, but it probably wasn't necessary.

Comment: *Remarks* in [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer) says that it runs on a ThreadPool thread. Same for System.Timers.Timer when the `SynchronizingObject` property is `null`, also in *Remarks*. So no need for a Task.

Comment: Clemens is right. The problem you have is that the normal timer always ticks on the UI thread so it's like you are running the code as part of the UI. System.Threading.Timer does not tick on the UI thread so you can't interact with the UI but it's won't hold up your UI.